# making phone calls with computer (not voip)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, phone, rj-11

I have an rj11 pci card on a computer I got. Is there a way I can plug it into my home phone jack and make calls? Does anyone know of a free software for Windows or Ubuntu that will work for that? Looking for guidance. Tried googling but getting only voip results which I don't want or care about.

Comment: The RJ11 jack that you see on the PCI card on your computer is a PCI Express Dial-up Faxmodem (PCIe). https://www.google.ae/search?q=dial+up+modem+in+pci+slot&rlz=1C1CHYD_enAE553AE553&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=679&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=vHwGVZTxLebQygO384LIDw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ. You cannot make phone calls with this I think

Comment: You probably can't practically use it to turn your computer into a regular phone as the device is almost certainly an old-style analog modem - although you can probably use it to dial numbers for your phone.    Its probably not worth the hassle as the technology is outdated - The words to google might include "Voice modem".  If you are very technically inclined also google "Hayes AT commands" and "hyperterm" - which is how you typically control these devices.

Comment: you need a modem to do that.  From there, instead of dialing an ISP (to get internet access), you dial a regular phone number.  Of course, you'll need software/mic/speakers to interact, but you CAN call a regular number with a modem

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice. Using this information I figured out how that I can dial out with this even though I have no audio.